# Interop.Excel - reading data types

Tags: c#, excel

I'm reading an excel file into c# and I only need the Rows that begin with a number. All of the cells are formatted as General. I tried testing to see if the value in the first column was a Double, and it worked. But some of the rows begin with '1' and some have a decimal place '1.1'. How can I sort the whole number from the decimals? Treat them as a string and test for '.'? My formatting options in excel seem to be either a the cell is a number, or not. I cant specify int, double or anything. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to distinguish between `1`, `1.00000000` and `1.00002312`?

Comment: No, it's an outline of categories and sub-categories. 2.6, 10.2... that would be the extent of it.

Comment: If you have a double, then `(val % 1) == 0` for whole numbers. The opposite is true if there is anything past the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using only Excel 2007/2010 (*.xlsx) files then you can use official Microsoft assembly (Open XML SDK) which have many powerfull futures (including row filtering by any condition): http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my purpose. I am able to read only the rows that begin with a number and filter the whole numbers from the decimals (whole numbers shown). Thank you for your help.

```
        Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        Range excelRange = sheet.UsedRange; 
        object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);

        for (int i = 1; i <= excelRange.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (valueArray[i, 1] is Double)
            {                   
                if (!valueArray[i, 1].ToString().Contains("."))
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(valueArray[i, 1].ToString()); 
                }
            }
        }
```